# upgrade on graphic card board memory

Tags: graphics-card

is it possible that the amount of memory available on a graphic card board be updated/altered? I' mot talking about the shared memory that the graphic controller might use from system memory (RAM). my question is:

"is it possible to replace/alter the memory available on the graphic card dedicated memory attached on the graphic board, with a similar memory but with higher capacity?"

Update:
by the upgrade I did not mean the user would do that, I meant the support service of the card manufacturer, or something like that with available tools and devices and access to original manufactured memories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Unlike many years ago the on card memory is not upgradable.  You would end up needing to upgrade the whole card.

Comment: the old ones (ancient, really) had memory in chip sockets and you could add new memory chips to empty sockets or replace existing chips.  the socket was what made it doable without a soldering iron.  with modern cards not even a basic soldering iron helps much.

Comment: actually I was not clear enough. I didn't mean the user changes the memory, the upgrade might be done by a technical team, the support service of the card manufacturer for example.

Comment: @farzad - It's technically possible but **very very** unlikely that someone would do this. Graphics cards are made by robots with sub-millimetre precision and are not constructed to be taken apart again. Even with most trivial repairs it would be cheaper to replace the whole card.

Comment: It would require a technician with skill in using a reflow workstation.  That is not cheap, and it is economically not in the companies best interest to offer such services.  It actually is very likely cheaper for them to produce a whole new board than to reflow for a few chips.